# SQL server scripting object date and database completeness

Tags: sql-server

I have a script that automatically overwrites SQL Server objects every 2 days.

In order to check whether the script has run successfully, I would like to be able to check two things:

1. Find out the freshness of the objects by retrieving the object creation (table, views,...) date. If it is older than 2 days, the script has not overwritten the objects. These objects have to be listed.
2. Find out the completeness of the objects by ensuring all objects are present based on a predefined list, ie check if all tables/views are present. The objects are already stored in another table on the database level, so this can be used as an input.

How to go about this? What would be the approach? Could you please refer me to any good online resources? What scripting language is used to realize this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can I ask why do you do that ? (and btw, why a successful execution of the script isn't enough ? )

Comment: This is readily do-able in T-SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT 
    mo.Name, 
    CASE 
        WHEN so.name IS NULL 
            THEN 'Does Not Exist' 
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, so.create_date, getdate()) > 2
                     THEN 'More than two days old'
             ELSE 'Exists' END    AS existCheck
FROM        dbo.MyObjects AS mo
LEFT JOIN   sys.objects   AS so ON so.name = mo.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the system tables then an unrelated release could throw you off. Use a log table to keep track of what is going on. On successful completion of your process have it insert an entry into the table that says it was completed. Then query the log table to see when you should refresh again.

Could be something as simple as the table below where activityTypeId = 1 for this process and activityType is zero for started and 1 for completed.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActivityLog](
        [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [activityTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [activityTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [activityValue] [int] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_ActivityLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM sys.objects O
    LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable T
        ON O.name = t.name
        AND O.modify_date < DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE())
    WHERE TYPE IN ('U','V')
)
    RAISERROR('Some objects have not been updated in the last 2 days', 16, 1)
```